# Python, how to perform an iterate formula?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

I'm trying to export from excel a formula that (as usual) iterate two other value. 
I'm trying to explain me better.

I have the following three variables:

```
iva_versamenti_totale,
utilizzato, 
riporto
```

`iva_versamenti_totale`have a len equal to 13 and it is given by the following formula

`iva_versamenti_totale={'Saldo IVA': [sum(t) for t in zip(*iva_versamenti.values())],}`

`Utilizzato` and `riporto` are simultaneously obtained in an iterate manner. I have tried to get the following code but does not work:

```
    utilizzato=dict()
    riporto=dict()

    for index, xi in enumerate(iva_versamenti_totale['Saldo IVA']):
      if xi > 0 :
          riporto[index] = riporto[index] + xi
      else:
          riporto[index] = riporto[index-1]-utilizzato[index]

    for index, xi in enumerate(iva_versamenti_totale['Saldo IVA']):
      if xi > 0 :
          utilizzato[index] == 0
      elif riporto[index-1] >= xi:
          utilizzato[index] = -xi
      else: 
          utilizzato[index]=riporto[index-1]
```

Python give me KeyError:0.

**EDIT** 
Here my excel file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SRp9uscUgYsV88991yTnZ8X4c8NElhuD

In grey input and in yellow the variables

Comment: what is your input

Comment: can you show us a simple excel you used?

Comment: `utilizzato[0]` `riporto[0]` and `iva_versamenti_totale` must be my input,

Comment: yep I update my answer

Comment: ok the `KeyError:0` means there is not any key 0 but I want your simple data for run your code and find the issue

Comment: I have added the excel file, you can find all the algo structure